# dtypes muck things up when shifting on axis one (columns)

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2], B=['X', 'Y']))

df

   A  B
0  1  X
1  2  Y
```

If I shift along `axis=0` (the default)

```
df.shift()

     A    B
0  NaN  NaN
1  1.0    X
```

It pushes all rows downwards one row as expected.

But when I shift along `axis=1`

```
df.shift(axis=1)

    A    B
0 NaN  NaN
1 NaN  NaN
```

Everything is null when I expected

```
     A  B
0  NaN  1
1  NaN  2
```

I understand why this happened.  For `axis=0`, Pandas is operating column by column where each column is a single `dtype` and when shifting, there is clear protocol on how to deal with the introduced `NaN` value at the beginning or end.  But when shifting along `axis=1` we introduce potential ambiguity of `dtype` from one column to the next.  In this case, I'm trying for force `int64` into an `object` column and Pandas decides to just null the values.

This becomes more problematic when the `dtypes` are `int64` and `float64`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2], B=[1., 2.]))

df

   A    B
0  1  1.0
1  2  2.0
```

And the same thing happens

```
df.shift(axis=1)

    A   B
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
```

---

## My Question

What are ***good*** options for creating a dataframe that is shifted along `axis=1` in which the result has shifted values and dtypes?

For the `int64`/`float64` case the result would look like:

```
df_shifted

     A  B
0  NaN  1
1  NaN  2
```

and

df_shifted.dtypes

```
A    object
B     int64
dtype: object
```

---

A more comprehensive example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2], B=[1., 2.], C=['X', 'Y'], D=[4., 5.], E=[4, 5]))

df

   A    B  C    D  E
0  1  1.0  X  4.0  4
1  2  2.0  Y  5.0  5
```

Should look like this

```
df_shifted

     A  B    C  D    E
0  NaN  1  1.0  X  4.0
1  NaN  2  2.0  Y  5.0

df_shifted.dtypes

A     object
B      int64
C    float64
D     object
E    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, what happens if you make the dtypes of all columns `object`?

Comment: It works.  I've already got a couple of work arounds.  I'm just poking the community for some ideas.

Comment: I'd file this as an issue, they should at least offer an option for dtype promotion to a mixed dtype such as `object`

Comment: I'll do that now.

Comment: @EdChum-ReinstateMonica Wait a minute!  The shift happens over `blocks` >.<  Use this instead and see `df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2], B=[3., 4.], C=['X', 'Y'], D=[5., 6.], E=[7, 8], F=['W', 'Z']))`

Comment: I think pandas tries to convert the shifted values to the type of the column that it shifts to

Comment: [Issue Opened](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29417)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that Pandas is shifting over blocks of similar `dtypes`

Define `df` as

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=[1, 2], B=[3., 4.], C=['X', 'Y'],
    D=[5., 6.], E=[7, 8], F=['W', 'Z']
))

df

#  i    f  o    f  i  o
#  n    l  b    l  n  b
#  t    t  j    t  t  j
#
   A    B  C    D  E  F
0  1  3.0  X  5.0  7  W
1  2  4.0  Y  6.0  8  Z
```

It will shift the integers to the next integer column, the floats to the next float column and the objects to the next object column

```
df.shift(axis=1)

    A   B    C    D    E  F
0 NaN NaN  NaN  3.0  1.0  X
1 NaN NaN  NaN  4.0  2.0  Y
```

I don't know if that's a good idea, but that **is** what is happening.

---

## Approaches

#### `astype(object)` first

```
dtypes = df.dtypes.shift(fill_value=object)
df_shifted = df.astype(object).shift(1, axis=1).astype(dtypes)

df_shifted

     A  B    C  D    E  F
0  NaN  1  3.0  X  5.0  7
1  NaN  2  4.0  Y  6.0  8
```

---

#### `transpose`

Will make it `object`

```
dtypes = df.dtypes.shift(fill_value=object)
df_shifted = df.T.shift().T.astype(dtypes)

df_shifted

     A  B    C  D    E  F
0  NaN  1  3.0  X  5.0  7
1  NaN  2  4.0  Y  6.0  8
```

---

#### `itertuples`

```
pd.DataFrame([(np.nan, *t[1:-1]) for t in df.itertuples()], columns=[*df])

     A  B    C  D    E  F
0  NaN  1  3.0  X  5.0  7
1  NaN  2  4.0  Y  6.0  8
```

Though I'd probably do this

```
pd.DataFrame([
    (np.nan, *t[:-1]) for t in
    df.itertuples(index=False, name=None)
], columns=[*df])
```

Comment: This is definitely a bug to me, this invalidates the whole point of having keyed columns and shifting by N positions column-wise

Comment: I'll post an issue after my meeting.

Comment: If it's all `str` dytpes then it works correctly, if you do the same on this df `df = pd.DataFrame(dict(C=['X', 'Y'], D=[5., 6.], E=[7, 8], F=['W', 'Z']))` it shifts the `'XY'` column all the way to `'F'` column, this is definitely wrong to me, my pandas version is `0.24.2`, it shoudl do `dtype` promotion and not shift the columns in such a way

Comment: [Issue Opened](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29417)

Answer (score 1):

I tried using a `numpy` method. The method works as long as you keep your data in a numpy array:

```
def shift_df(data, n):
    shifted = np.roll(data, n)
    shifted[:, :n] = np.NaN

    return shifted

shifted(df, 1)

array([[nan, 1, 1.0, 'X', 4.0],
       [nan, 2, 2.0, 'Y', 5.0]], dtype=object)
```

But when you call the `DataFrame` constructer, all columns are converted to `object` although the values in the array are `float, int, object`:

```
def shift_df(data, n):
    shifted = np.roll(data, n)
    shifted[:, :n] = np.NaN
    shifted = pd.DataFrame(shifted)

    return shifted

print(shift_df(df, 1),'\n')
print(shift_df(df, 1).dtypes)

     0  1  2  3  4
0  NaN  1  1  X  4
1  NaN  2  2  Y  5 

0    object
1    object
2    object
3    object
4    object
dtype: object
```